# How can i allow traffic coming at specific Port in IPtables Rules

Tags: iptables, telnet, firewalld

I have centos7 running in 2 VM's. firewall is running on both VM machines.
Suppose some application is running on machine A which  is using 5044 port. 
and i have another machine called machine B who trying to telnet this machine on 5044 port. On that time telnet is through the exception saying

```
Trying 192.168.115.141...
   telnet: connect to address 192.168.115.141: No route to host
```

But after shutdown firewall communication is working fine. But i don't want to disable firewall. So, How can i allow another machine B to Communicate with Machine A. Do you have any idea where and what kind of policy i need to define in IP-tables or firewall-rule list.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Centos 7 is using [`firewalld`](http://www.firewalld.org/) by default. It is currently a higher level interface to kernel's provided firewall [`iptables`](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables). While no real knowledge of `iptables` is asked to use `firewalld`, a good comprehension of it can certainly help. The main interface to control `firewalld` is the [`firewall-cmd`](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html) command. When this command is used with `--permanent` it will affect only the configuration and have no visible effect (until a reload, a service restart or a reboot). When this option is not present, it will only have immediately visible effects, without changing the saved configuration. Other interfaces exist, for example a GUI [`firewall-config`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-configuring_firewalld#sec-Configuring_firewalld_using_firewall-config).

`firewalld` has many abstract concepts, like [zones](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls#sec-Understanding_Network_Zones). By default the public zone is in use but many are predefined (trusted, work, dmz ...), each having an usage role and including some predefined settings (eg: ssh is allowed by default in the public zone). For a service access restricted for specific sources only, using an alternate zone (than public) should be preferred. Perhaps a predefined zone should be elected, but anyway, let's just create a new one, tie it with a source (MachineB's IP) and allow the TCP port 5044. Let's say MachineB's IP is `10.0.3.66` (an other valid source would be for example all the LAN as source, for this example that would be `10.0.3.0/24` instead):

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone peervm
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone peervm --add-source 10.0.3.66
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone peervm --add-port 5044/tcp
```

Effects in the configuration are visible with for example:

```
# egrep -r '10.0.3.66|5044' /etc/firewalld
/etc/firewalld/zones/peervm.xml.old:  <source address="10.0.3.66"/>
/etc/firewalld/zones/peervm.xml:  <source address="10.0.3.66"/>
/etc/firewalld/zones/peervm.xml:  <port protocol="tcp" port="5044"/>
```

The change is activated with this command:

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

This will rebuild the underlying `iptables` rules, with the effects visible for example with:

```
# iptables-save |egrep '10.0.3.66|5044'
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE -d 10.0.3.66/32 -g POST_peervm
-A PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE -s 10.0.3.66/32 -g PRE_peervm
-A PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE -s 10.0.3.66/32 -g PRE_peervm
-A PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE -s 10.0.3.66/32 -g PRE_peervm
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE -s 10.0.3.66/32 -g FWDI_peervm
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE -d 10.0.3.66/32 -g FWDO_peervm
-A INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE -s 10.0.3.66/32 -g IN_peervm
-A IN_peervm_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5044 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Using an abstraction layer can generate a lot of boilerplate rules like above for what could be basically done with only one `iptables` rule (put among a few standard rules not shown here):

```
# iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.3.66/32 -p tcp --dport 5044 -j ACCEPT
```

So, when proficient with `iptables`, for the simpliest cases, or at the other end of the spectrum, for very complex cases not easily covered with `firewalld`, one should consider using direct `iptables` rules with an other set of saved configuration tools instead, for example on CentOS by using [`iptables-services`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_iptables) instead of `firewalld`.